# Take a random n number array of elements and insert them in a specified element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random

I have a list of books that are embedded frame elements. I'm wanting to return three of those books and insert them into a `div` I've already defined. I'm trying to utilize the shuffle method, but something isn't going right as I can't get the elements to display or randomize.

The code below is the example I'm trying to work with.

**Javascript**

```
   function randomBooks(arr, count) {

   var arr = [ // list of books
   '<iframe type="text/html" width="150" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%" src="https://read.amazon.com/kp/card?asin=B00ARFNQ54&asin=B00ARFNQ54&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_wpdGxbH9ZAXX9&hideShare=true" ></iframe>',
   '<iframe type="text/html" width="150" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%" src="https://read.amazon.com/kp/card?asin=B00AFH1TBC&asin=B00AFH1TBC&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_5udGxbAPXN07Q&hideShare=true" ></iframe>',
   '<iframe type="text/html" width="150" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%" src="https://read.amazon.com/kp/card?asin=B005GSYZRA&asin=B005GSYZRA&preview=inline&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_FxdGxbYXKDM2P&hideShare=true" ></iframe>',
   '<iframe type="text/html" width="150" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%" src="https://read.amazon.com/kp/card?asin=B00ARFNQ54&asin=B00ARFNQ54&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_wpdGxbH9ZAXX9&hideShare=true" ></iframe>',
   '<iframe type="text/html" width="150" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%" src="https://read.amazon.com/kp/card?asin=B00AFH1TBC&asin=B00AFH1TBC&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_5udGxbAPXN07Q&hideShare=true" ></iframe>',
   '<iframe type="text/html" width="150" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="max-width:100%" src="https://read.amazon.com/kp/card?asin=B005GSYZRA&asin=B005GSYZRA&preview=inline&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_FxdGxbYXKDM2P&hideShare=true" ></iframe>'

   ];    

   var insertDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("bookFrame"); // Div I want elements inserted

   var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, min = i - count, temp, index;
   while (i-- > min) {
       index = Math.floor((i + 1) * Math.random());
       temp = shuffled[index];
       shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
       shuffled[i] = temp;
   }

   var returnedValue= shuffled.slice(min, 3);
   insertDiv.innerHTML(returnedValue); // inject 3 random book elements

   alert( randomBooks(arr, 3)); // Checking 

   };
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="center bookFrame">

<!-- Insert books here -->

</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things might not have been working for a few reasons.  There were a bunch of little errors in the code.

Your **randomBooks()** method accepts an argument arr, but you then overwrote it with your own.  I think you might have wanted to pass in the array of books into your randomizer so I did that in my example.

Secondly, **getElementsByClassName()** returns an array.  You might want to take the first element of it or switch to **querySelector()** if you know that you want the first of selector found.

Finally, **el.innerHTML** is directly assigned to.  You have used it more like how jQuery's **$el.html()** method works.

```js
function addBooks(target, bookIds, count) {
  // -----------------------------
  // A classic array shuffler (inplace).
  // -----------------------------
  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }
  // -----------------------------

  // -----------------------------
  // Get 3 random books.
  // -----------------------------
  shuffleArray(bookIds);
  var selected = bookIds.slice(0, 3);
  // -----------------------------
  
  // -----------------------------
  // Construct some HTML for the 3 books.
  // -----------------------------
  var html = selected.map(function(bookId){
    var retval = '<iframe type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://read.amazon.com/kp/card?asin=' + bookId + '&asin=' + bookId + '&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_wpdGxbH9ZAXX9&hideShare=true" ></iframe>';
    return retval;
  });
  // -----------------------------

  // -----------------------------
  // inject 3 random book elements
  // -----------------------------
  document.querySelector(target).innerHTML = html;
  // -----------------------------
};

var bookIds = [
  'B00ARFNQ54',
  'B00AFH1TBC',
  'B005GSYZRA',
  'B00ARFNQ54',
  'B00AFH1TBC',
  'B005GSYZRA'
];

addBooks(".bookFrame", bookIds, 3);
```

```css
iframe { width: 150px; height: 200px; max-width:100%; }
```

```html
<p class="center bookFrame"><!-- Insert books here --></p>
```

Comment: This is a really smart way of doing this! Having the book ID's be the only items in the array is a good step. Thank you for a very clear and explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in this code.

First, the `alert( randomBooks(arr, 3)); // Checking` appears to be inside the function randomBooks itself, so clearly it will never be called..

Secondly, you can't do `insertDiv.innerHTML(returnedValue);` as 'innerHTML' is a string, not a function. And the return value of getElementsByClassName is a list and not a single element, so it should have been something like:

```
insertDiv[0].innerHTML = returnedValue;
```

There might be more errors, it looks like this code never really ran, so I suggest you start executing it and see how it goes first.

Just a tip: for testing purposes, instead of adding random calls and alerts to the code you could use the developer console (in chrome its F12, go to the console tab and just call randomBooks() from there to see what it returns).

Comment: Another issue with the code is that                                                        `var insertDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("bookFrame"); ` gets an array of elements instead of the element.                                   `var insertDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("bookFrame")**[0]**; ` should fix this problem.

Comment: yeah I mentioned that (even before my edit), but thanks anyway